# Parse webpage (scrape) return two elements from span class tags

Tags: python, python-requests, scrape

wizards and wizardesses of the Internet.
I'm trying to get two elements from a web page (essentially scraping) it to get the text.

I'm using Python Requests, and now starting to play with Beautiful Soup, but still to no avail.

Here is the bare bones of the code, I've butchered with other things I've found.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://flightaware.com/live/flight/EZY6878')
print("The status code is ", res.status_code)
print("\n")
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup_data.title)
print("\n")

spans = soup_data.find_all('span', {'class' : 'destinationCity'})

print(spans)
```

The URL is in the request get. I've tried printing (spans).text, spans[0].text, and blindly fumbling around.

The Destination City (in this case) is Glasgow

[image: Screenshot from website]

This is what is returned in terminal...

```
The status code is  200

<title>U26878 (EZY6878) easyJet Flight Tracking and History - FlightAware</title>


[]
```

Comment: This happens because the relevant page content is created with JavaScript. When you request the page JavaScript is not run and you only get the HTML, so the content hasn't been created yet. This is probably because FlightAware want you to pay for their API instead.

Comment: Thanks @henry, as I got into it a little more, there are more javascript injections than I care to deal with. Makes total sense what you said. Thankyou